# Как сделать динамечное сообщение меню в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Пишу бота в телеграмме. Делаю сообщение-меню пользовательских настроек - пока что уведомления и гиперник(ник с ссылкой на пользователя). Выносятся все значения настроек из базы данных (0 - выключена, 1 - включена). Хочу сделать, чтобы когда функция была включена, в тексте в сообщении писалось (✅), а когда выключен - (❌), как сделать такую проверку - беспонятия. Мог бы кто нибудь помочь в этом вопросе?

```py
def settings(message):
    user_name = message.from_user.id

    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    notification = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Уведомления', callback_data=notification)
    nickname_status = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Гиперникнейм', callback_data=nickname_status)
    keyboard.add(notification, nickname_status)

    cur.execute('SELECT notification, nickname_status FROM users WHERE user_id=("%s")' % user_name)
    users = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()

    for user in users:
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, text=f'Настройки:\n\nУведомления: {user[0]}\nГиперникнейм: {user[1]}', reply_markup=keyboard)

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: ну, раз вы получаете из базы `1` или `0`, то и отправляйте нужный текст, в зависимости от того, что прилетело из базы `IF / ELSE`

Comment: так если у меня сейчас только две функции в настройках и каждая будет имеет свое статус работы, слишком много будет расписывать столько вариантов текстов

Comment: не совсем понятно в каких сообщениях вы это хотите отправлять и о каких двух функциях идет речь

Comment: вы в `notification` и `nickname_status` получаете из БД `1` или `0`?

Comment: @ZxNuClear Да, получаю из них

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, раз вы получаете статусы из БД в виде `1` и `0`, то и выдавайте необходимый текст, согласно полученным статусам, например так:

```
for user in users:
    msg = f'Настройки:\n\nУведомления: {"✅" if user[0] else "❌"}\nГиперникнейм: {"✅" if user[1] else "❌"}'
```

При `notification == 0` и `nickname_status == 1` вывод такой получается:

```
Настройки:

Уведомления: ❌
Гиперникнейм: ✅
```